# SQL/PHP real-time changes to websites

Tags: php, sql

How can I allow user input on a page to change the HTML or CSS or anything. Is there a technique for this? I.e. If it is client-side web design, how can I have input from a form moved to a certain page and displayed to replace previous content. Let's say there is a main page with four links: Home, About, Links, Contact. In the admin-edit page, there is a form to enter, edit, delete links. Would I need a SQL database with the links' values that would populate this page and the other? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: have you looked into anything yet?  What have you tried?  Do you have any code examples to show?

Comment: Well my idea is that the whole page can be loaded in terms of SQL using PHP to provide an output to the HTML. However, I cannot see how I could create new content using this method.

Comment: (No I don't have code yet, it's just in the planning stages.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is javascript I believe.  You can use any amount of Javascript or Jquery ( A javascript library) in order to do various things on a page after it has been loaded.  In Jquery you attach "Listners" to divs and spans and whatever HTML elements you want that react in different ways such as the mouse hovering over, clicks, and such.

You can find the API for jquery here: http://jquery.com/

If you want to make permanent changes to some setting and such then yes you would need PHP along with a SQL database in order to store the results.  You would have to make panels for adding things to the database, editing, and retrieving them by using SQL insert, update, and select statements.  You can read a bunch on how these things work at http://www.w3schools.com/
Good luck :)

Comment: What I mean is that the pages are forever saved (until they are next changed). A way to write to the HTML. Is Javascript the only good way to do this? Are there no other ways to create content on a page and actually save it to the HTML file?

Comment: Refresh the page, i made an edit to my post.  If you are only doing very basic things you may want to look into finding a CMS to use.  If you plan on building this website from the ground up then you are going to need to use a bunch of PHP and SQL in order to store values into rows of data in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You want to change values in the "first" page in realtime using "second" page?

You can do this with javascript, given that the "second" page is opened by the "first" page using **window.open('second.html','second_page')**

Then in the "second" page, you can manipulate the "first" page by using something like **opener.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML = 'some text here';**